# Why do we multiply two wavefunctions in valence bond theory instead of adding them?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

The combined wavefunction of a hydrogen molecule in valence bond theory is the product of two wavefunctions, while in molecular orbital theory it is the sum of two wavefunctions.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the MO theory wavefunction can also be written as a product. While the individual molecular orbitals are just weighted sums of the atomic orbitals, the wavefunction can, to a first approximation, be written as a [Slater determinant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant) of the occupied orbitals.

For your example of the hydrogen molecule, this would mean taking the antisymmetrized product of the occupied $\sigma$ spin orbitals. (Note, if you haven't encountered this before, spin orbitals are a spatial and spin description of a single electron, rather than the commonly encountered spatial orbitals which describe two electrons of opposite spin.